# Ubuntu 14.04 + Hyperthreading

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Intel Core i7-2620m , (2.7 Ghz). I've checked in the bios that hyperthreading is activated, but on when doing less /proc/cpuinfo, hyperthreading appears off (sibling count = cpu count). Is there any specific configuration step i need to make in Ubuntu?

Comment: There is no *cpu count* metric, how are you counting the physical cores? Does *siblings* say 2 or 4?

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo shows 4 cpus with id 0 to 3, and sibling 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /proc/cpuinfo shows 4 cpus with id 0 to 3, and sibling 4

The [Intel® Core™ i7-2620M](http://ark.intel.com/products/52231/Intel-Core-i7-2620M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz) has two physical and four virtual cores.

`/proc/cpuinfo` shows each *virtual* core as a separate processor. If you're seeing four of them, hyperthreading is working as intended.